# Empty tool-tip in Developer Story Beta

Tags: bug, developer-story

I see a warning symbol in my Developer Story Beta tab. Hover on the warning icon, I got a empty tool-tip.

So I'm unable to find why I got the warning icon in the tab.

Zoom: `100%`
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
Firefox Version: `45.0.2`
Chrome Version: `50.0.2661.87 m`
Internet Explorer: `11.0.30`

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Empty tool-tip in Developer Story Beta]

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Happens in Windows 8.1 pro, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Sigh, No one to test on IE :-(

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 15.10, Firefox 45.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Verified in IE 11, the same issue is exist.